# GCP Cloud Build - Running Bash script with arguments

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

I have a GCP Cloub build configuration, where a bash script is needed to be executed.

The below configuration works just fine.

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: ['./my_script.sh']
```

But, I want to be able to pass the Build_ID as an argument to the bash script.
e.g.:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: ['./my_script.sh ${BUILD_ID}']
```

This doesn't work, unfortunately.

I get an error such as:
 `bash: ./my_script.sh 204792d1-6336-489b-ba20-fbce7401a40b: No such file or directory`

Any help on this is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to parametrize arguments, with:

```
steps:
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    entrypoint: 'bash'
    args: ['./my_script.sh', '${BUILD_ID}']
```

Comment: Amazing!! This works. Thank you very much, it's a life saver!